# How to make a function that accepts another one with argument tuple

Tags: c++, tuples

I need a function My_func that works like this

```
auto f = [](const std::tuple<string, double>& t) { return std::get<0>(t); };
    assert(My_func(f)("Hello", 8.5) == f({"Hello", 8.5}));
```

Now i have

```
template <class F>
constexpr auto My_func(F&& f) {
    return [f](auto&& args...) { return std::forward<F>(f)(args); };
}
```

But it doesn't work.What should i fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <class F>
constexpr auto My_func(F&& f) 
{
   return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&... args) { 
        return f(std::make_tuple(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...)); 
   };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need `My_func` to be syntactically valid. You have a pack `args` that is not expanded in the lambda. Then you need to mention `tuple` somewhere. C++ is not psychic.

Luckily, there exists [`std::forward_as_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple) that does exactly what you need here

```
template <class F>
constexpr auto My_func(F&& f) {
    return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](auto&& args...) { return f(std::forward_as_tuple(args...)); };
}
```