# How to make a function that accepts another one with variable arguments

Tags: c++, tuples

I need a function My_func that works like this

```
   auto f = [](string s, double c) { return c; };
    assert(My_func(f)(std::make_tuple("Hello", 8.5)) == f("Hello", 8.5'));
```

Now i have

```
template <class T>
auto My_func(T&& f) {
    return [f = std::forward<T>(f)](auto&& value) {

    };
}
```

What should i add?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a function that accepts another one with argument tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69461396/how-to-make-a-function-that-accepts-another-one-with-argument-tuple)

Comment: *What should i add?* I guess you could call `f` inside `My_func`. But that is up to you really and since you keep the requirements secret I do not know how to help you.

Comment: I need the opposite function

Comment: I do not know what "opposite" means in this context. Opposite to what?

Comment: opposite to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69461396/how-to-make-a-function-that-accepts-another-one-with-argument-tuple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `std::apply`

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template <class F>
constexpr auto My_func(F&& f) {
    return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](auto&& tuple) mutable {
        return std::apply(std::forward<decltype(f)>(f),
                          std::forward<decltype(tuple)>(tuple));
    };
}
int main() {
    auto f = [](std::string s, double c) { return c; };
    assert(My_func(f)(std::make_tuple("Hello", 8.5)) == f("Hello", 8.5));
}
```

This is essentially just a functor wrapper for `std::apply`, that is still useful because it would not be possible to pass it around due to it being a template.

Comment: Thank you,@Quimby.I want to add that we don't need to write
```
std::forward<decltype(f)>(f)
```
after forwarding "f" before.And we should write ```mutable``` after ```(auto&& tuple)``` if we want our function works with rvalue function
like this
```
My_func(std::move(f))("str", 3.9))
```

Comment: @Art_Uspen You are correct about the missing mutable, thanks.The `forward` in capture list is needed, otherwise capture by copy is done which will cause compiler errors for move-only types. The forward inside the call is also needed to move the capture value again - that's the reason for `mutable`. It makes the call dangerous because the functor works only once though, so maybe it should not be there.